# Firewall rules with tags not working properly

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created the firewall rules listed below to connect our Application Server to our Postgres Server.  However, it doesn't seem to be working properly.

**Rule Name: postgresql**

> Network default
>
> Source tags
>
> http-server https-server app-server
>
> Allowed protocols and ports
>
> tcp:5432
>
> Target tags
>
> postgres db

With only that rule turned on, my servers with the tag of 'app-server' are unable to connect to the Postgres server, which has the tag 'postgres'

I have confirmed that this rule isn't working, and the problem isn't related to the Windows Firewall or Postgres config because if I add this rule, then the app-server is able to connect to the postgres server.

**Rule Name: postgres-all**

> Network
> default
>
> Source filter
>
> Allow from any source (0.0.0.0/0)
>
> Allowed protocols and ports
>
> tcp:5432
>
> Target tags
>
> postgres

However, I don't want to leave that firewall rule on, as that opens Postgres to everything.  I want to only open Postgres to our app servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which IP address does the Application Server use to connect to the DB?
If you're not using the private IP (usually on the default network this is 10.x.x.x) then a rule that requires source tags is not sufficient to allow connections.

See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls:

> Note: Source tags cannot be used to allow access to an instance's external IP address. Because tags are associated with an instance, not an IP address, source tags can only be used to control traffic traveling from an instance inside the same network as the firewall.

Comment: Thanks!  I had the Application Server connecting to the DB over its external address, and had forgotten about that.  I switched it to the internal and its working now.